# Rails 5, Ajax, jQuery - Cant send received data to particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So, I have partial where is a table row and different table datas. By clicking a button (which is in `<tr>`) I send Ajax request (simply, with `remote: true`) and also update item data (displayed in `<tr>`) with action.

It all goes fine, but I can't send received data from Ajax to specific `<td>`. If more items being displayed - all of them receives that data.

**_partial.html.er**b:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <tr data-line-item-id='<%= line_item.id %>' class='line-item'>
      <td data-th="Product">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.product.price) %></td>
      <td data-th="Quantity">
        <%= line_item.quantity %>
      </td>
      <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center" class="subtotal">
        <%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price, :unit => "€", separator: ",", format: "%n %u") %></td>
      <td class="actions" data-th="">
        <td><%= link_to "-", decrease_line_item_path(product_id: line_item.product), remote: true %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "+", increase_line_item_path(product_id: line_item.product), remote: true %></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</body>
```

**decrease.js.erb**:

```
$("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
```

My 'nice tries' were something like:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
```

But my '*best achievement*' was to update only the particular, found by number item, like this:

```
$("td[data-th='Quantity']").eq(0).html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
```

Otherwise they all get updated...

**UPDATE**

This, kinda made it working, but if I increase numbers of one item and then increase other item numbers, first click shows the number of previously updated item number... But answer is close. Hope someone could help... Many thanks

**increase.js.erb**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.increase').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).parent().parent()
    $(element).find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
  });
});
```

Comment: You want to increase/decrease number of items in that row alone on click on +/- buttons right in the same row?

Comment: Yes.  But that is accomplished. Now my concern is why when I increase or decrease number of one item, and click increase/decrease button on other item, first click shows number of previously increased or decreased items (second click represents the right number). I assume its something with Ajax request, like that data is still stored in the flow. I am totaly new to Ajax, so now trying to read it and understand something

Comment: `$('.increase')`, have you written this in `increase.js.erb` or `decrease.js.erb`?

Comment: yes, I updated my question to show which code represents `increase.js.erb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add click event in js.erb file in your case as when the page loads **increase.js.erb**'s click function is not available.

Lets say current quantity is 2.

Now on first click AJAX request is sent, in response `$('.increase')` function is loaded but it will not execute as the first click happened before the AJAX response.

def increase
  # quantity is increased to 3.
end

The increase function which just loaded will have new incremented number.

```
// first click function loaded not triggered.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.increase').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).parent().parent()
    // $(element).find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
    $(element).find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('3');
   // but as the click is not triggered in first click, the value has changed to 3.
  });
});
```

On second click on increase button, the first click function gets executed, changing the value of the `td cell` to 3. And in response to AJAX call of 2nd click on increase button, one more `$('.increase').click()` is loaded with a value 4. But again this newly loaded function doesn't execute.

```
// second click function loaded not triggered in response to second click.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.increase').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).parent().parent()
    // $(element).find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
    $(element).find("td[data-th='Quantity']").html('4');
   // but as the click is not triggered in second click, the value has changed to 4.
  });
});
// this 2nd function will get executed on third click.
```

#### decrease.js.erb

```
$('tr[data-line-item-id]').each(function(){
  if ($(this).data('line-item-id') == '<%= @line_item.id %>' ){
    $(this).each(function(){
      if ( $(this).data('th') == 'Quantity' ) {
        $(this).html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This can be made a lot simpler if you add an id attribute to each `tr`, for example:

```
<tr data-line-item-id='<%= line_item.id %>' id='row-<%= line_item.id %>' class='line-item'>
   ---
</tr>
```

and then access it in **decrease.js.erb** like this:

```
$('#row-<%= @line_item.id %> td:nth-child(3)').html('<%= @line_item.quantity %>');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out later. Some of the syntax is a bit unfamiliar

Comment: That previous comment made sense. Could you answer two questions? 1 why .increase is not available? 2 Why you write row- in this id='row-<%= line_item.id %>'? Thank you

Comment: It's because `js.erb` will only be loaded in response to  AJAX response, so it is not available till the result loads.

Comment: OK.... Now it is very obvious... Once again... :) Many thanks. Looks like it is working all fine now!

Comment: You can have any **ID** value for each row, but imagine if we just have `<tr id="1">, <tr id="2">`, this might break at some point due to multiple elements having same **ID**, instead we can append a word to the number, you can have anything like, `<tr id="quantity-2">`. **ID** allows us to target the elements in a better way.

Comment: ah, I was expecting something magical :D But that makes sense as well :) Cheers!